# Dynamically generating rail validation methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to dry up some code in a Rails mode.

I have 4 validators that I'm trying to dry up by using define_method but it's not working correctly. You can see my attempts commented out below and the original methods below that.
At best I get no validation, at worst I get:

undefined local variable or method `validate_weight'

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

PRODUCT_DIMENSION_FIELDS = [:weight, :height, :width, :depth]

....

PRODUCT_DIMENSION_FIELDS.each do |meth|
  #define_method('validate_' + meth.to_s) do
  #  errors.add(meth, "can't be blank") if has_parents? && meth.empty?
  #end

  #define_singleton_method('validate_' + meth.to_s) do
  #  errors.add(meth, "can't be blank") if has_parents? && meth.empty?
  #end

  #self.class.send(:define_method, ('validate_' + meth.to_s).to_sym) do
  #  errors.add(meth, "can't be blank") if has_parents? && meth.empty?
  #end

end

# attempting to dry up these methods

def validate_weight
  errors.add(:weight , "can't be blank") if has_parents? && weight.empty?
end

def validate_height
  errors.add(:height , "can't be blank") if has_parents? && height.empty?
end

def validate_width
  errors.add(:width , "can't be blank") if has_parents? && width.empty?
end

def validate_depth
  errors.add(:depth , "can't be blank") if has_parents? && depth.empty?
end

end
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the normal presence validator?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  PRODUCT_DIMENSION_FIELDS = [:weight, :height, :width, :depth]

  validates_presence_of *PRODUCT_DIMENSION_FIELDS, if: :has_parents?

end
```

Comment: I have to check it's empty as well as :has_parents? I couldnt seem to get :if to work with both :has_parents? and :empty? at the same time. Is there a way to use both?